# Ambiguous reference to member 'count'

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, swift2

Getting the following error when i migrated my current Xcode (v 7.0.1) project  to Xcode 7.1.1

- Ambiguous reference to member 'count'
- Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array'

Any idea how to resolve above errors?

My code is as follows

```
  var arrOfRewardDetail : Array = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->  Int {
    return arrOfRewardDetail.count //Ambiguous reference to member 'count'
}

 if self.arrOfRewardDetail[indexPath.row]["KEY"] == "Promotion By : "{} // Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array'
```

**Update** Now getting the following errors

- Ambiguous reference to member 'indexOf'
  `let indexOfEnum : Int = self.arrPromitionDetailEnum.indexOf(dictRewardInfo["r_promotion_detail_type"]!)!`
- Also this one
  `let indexOfEnum : Int = self.arrPromitionDetailEnum.indexOf(dictInfo["r_promotion_detail_type"]!)! // Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array'`

Comment: Have you tried to remove `:Array` ? That would leave just `var arrOfRewardDetail = [Dictionary<String, String>]()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove the `: Array` part:

```
var arrOfRewardDetail = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

The compiler will infer the right type, which is `[Dictionary<String, String>]`, not just `Array`.

Comment: @RahulMathur delete the self.

Comment: Yup done.. Thanks
Can you explain the technical aspects of the errors. What went wrong in Xcode 7.1.1 ?

Comment: About `:Array`: Swift 1 was more tolerant about types. Now with Swift 2 the compiler demands more context, so `Array` was too ambiguous, it needed the actual type for the array which was `[[String:String]]` (array of dictionaries). About `self.`: I'm not sure how to explain it in English (this was @LeoDabus's hint, maybe he can explain you).

Comment: Self inside view controller would be referencing the view controller not the array